# Symfony 4.2 event POST_SUBMIT is returning null

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.2

Im doing 3 forms in Symfony 4.2.5 all with the same code when load states and cities (estados and municipios) but only this form is making me crazy because has the same code that all but doesnt work it always return null in "municipio", and when I print $request it has municipio=1 but in $form->isValid() says that municipio is null and it started when I added FormEvents

Please if someone could help me I'll be grateful, I inspected all my code but this is where its break.

```
$builder->get('estado')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $estado = $event->getForm()->getData();

        if (null == $estado) {
            $event->getForm()->getParent()->add('municipio', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Municipio',
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => '== Selecciona un municipio 1==',
                'choices' => []
            ]);
        } else {
            $event->getForm()->getParent()->add('municipio', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Municipio',
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => '== Selecciona un municipio 2 ==',
                'choices' => $estado->getMunicipios()
            ]);
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the POST_SUBMIT eventListener?

Comment: Are you trying to access the initial data the form was populated with or do you want to use the data submitted by the user?

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for your help but I had duplicated my field, one in buildForm and other in the event and cause bad behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I had duplicated my field, one in buildForm when add and other in the event and cause bad behaviour.

Symfony dont say that we can not add a field more than 1 time and no error is showing until I needed submit the form and my field was not recognized and always had null value.

I just deleted $builder->add('municipio') and all work fine.